# Mean time spent in transient states/Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I dont get this in my book:

For transient states $i$ and $j$ , let $s_{ij}$ denote the expected number of time periods that the markov chain is in state $j$ , given that it starts in state $i$. Let $\delta_{i,j} = 1$ when $i = j$ and let it be $0$ otherwise.Condition of the initial transition to obtain:

$s_{ij} = \delta_{i,j} + \sum_k P_{ik}s_{kj} = \delta_{i,j} + \sum\limits^t P_{ik}s_{kj} $

can someone show me how , if i condition of the initial transition, obtain the above equation ?  or explain in how do interpret the equation?

Answer (score 6):

If you start in j, then you automatically get one count of being in the target state. Now pick your next transition k. Do a weighted average of the expected number of visits from k to j, where you weigh by the probability of going to a particular k first.

Let $S_{j}$ be a random variable that counts the number of times one visits state $j$.

$$ S_{j} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{X_n = j}$$
$$ s_{ij} = E[S_j | X_1 = i] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E[1_{X_n = j} | X_1 = i]$$
$$ = \delta_{ij} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty E[1_{X_n = j} | X_1 = i] $$
$$ = \delta_{ij} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_k P_{ik} E[1_{X_n = j} | X_1 = i,X_2=k] $$

Used what's sometimes called the "Law of total expectation" above. Now you can use the Markov property and switch the order of summation

$$ = \delta_{ij} + \sum_k P_{ik} E\left[\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1_{X_n = j} | X_2=k\right] $$
The sums inside the expectation above is basically like what we took for the definition of $s_{kj}$, except the first index is shifted from $1$ to $2$; that doesn't matter for the expectation. 
$$ = \delta_{ij} + \sum_k P_{ik} s_{kj}$$

Comment: what about that $\delta_{i,j}$ what function does it have

Comment: Thats what my first sentence explains.

Comment: thanks for your answer but how would it look like if i would: as they said: Condition of the initial transition to obtain: ..the above equation..  ? ??   @Kai Sikorski

Comment: Thats exactly what is being described above..

Comment: @Danny I added some more details.

Comment: One thing i don't get is how you get the $P_{ik}$  in $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_k P_{ik} E[1_{X_n = j} | X_1 = i,X_2=k]$ . (i know it is probably an elementary thing i dont get)why does it appear?  @Kai Sikorski

Comment: @Danny did you look up the "Law of total expectation" that I say I use?

Comment: yeah but $P_{ik} = P( X_2 =k \vert X_1 = i )$ but using the law of total expectation i would get $P(X_2 = k , X_1 = i)$ right? and thats not $P_{ik}$ @Kai Sikorski

Comment: No, the expectation you're computing is to begin with conditioned on $X_1 = i$. You want $P(X_2 = k | X_1 = i)$.

Comment: one could add in the end, that in order for us to obtain the ^t in the summation (which is the label for "all transient states"), we just need to state that we can't co from recurrent to transient.